# What is Config.ast_impl_magic_number used for when generating ocaml AST

Tags: ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree, reason

I'm looking through the reasonml code and I found `Config.ast_intf_magic_number` in the file that outputs the AST.

What is this number for and why is it needed?

Reference:
https://github.com/facebook/reason/blob/master/src/refmt/reason_interface_printer.ml#L48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a binary file identifier that marks the file as a cmi for a specific OCaml version.